# Recompile the kernel changing only one option

Tags: kernel

I've already built a custom kernel based on the mainline 4.1.6. Now I want to disable `CONFIG_ACPI_I2C_OPREGION`

The kernel build is not very short, so I'd like to rebuild only the parts affected by a change in the config.

Is it possible? Can I simply edit `.config`, run `make oldconfig` and `make` without cleaning? Or do I have to rebuild from scratch?

Comment: This depends on which kernel modules are affected by `CONFIG_ACPI_I2C_OPREGION`, if it's just one, you may follow the directions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module

Comment: I don't know. I'm eager to know an universal rule, so let's assume that there are many.